# Can't implicitly convert int to model type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

Hi I have two model classes for technician and profession I gave relationship to the tables by crating profession foreign key column I want to create Dropdownlist with that foreign key column when I map this model to SqlReader for insert function  I've got error like cannot implicitly convert int to model.profession.

**model code** :

```
public class Technician
{   
     [ScaffoldColumn (false)]
     public int Id { get; set; }

     [Required]
     [Display(Name = "Name")]
     public string Name { get; set; }


     [Required]
     public Profession Profession { get; set; }

}

public class Profession
{
    [Key]
    public int ProfessionId { get; set; }
    public string ProfessionType { get; set; }
}
```

**Db class code** :

```
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{
    Technician technician = new Technician();
    technician.Id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["techId"]);

    technician.Name = dr["techName"].ToString();

    technician.Profession = Convert.ToInt32(dr["primeProfessionId"]);
    Jobtechnicians.Add(technician);`
}
```

Comment: `technician.Profession = Convert.ToInt32(dr["primeProfessionId"]);` - this line of code tries to assign an int value to a property that is a `Profession` - not an int. Rethink what you're trying to do because it's not at all clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is very clear here. `cannot implicitly convert int to model.profession` Compiler says it doesn't know how to convert an `Int32` to `Profession`.

```
technician.Profession = Convert.ToInt32(dr["primeProfessionId"]);
```

In the above line you're trying to set `int` value to `Profession`.

I assume `Profession` is a class. So you've to set instance of `Profession` there.

Somthing like this

```
technician.Profession = FindProfessionByProfessionId(Convert.ToInt32(dr["primeProfessionId"]));

private Profession FindProfessionByProfessionId(int professionId)
{
    //find profession instance or create one and return here 
}
```