# Can't implicitly convert int to model type in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to enter the last generated id of the user into another table column. I tried the following things.

Controller:

```
public void AddCartDetails(int id, int num)
{
    Cart cart = new()
                {
                    CartNumber = num,
                    User = id,
                    CartQty = 0,
                    CartTotal = 0
                };

    _repository.AddCart(cart);

    if (_repository.SaveAll())
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

When I tried this I am getting an error

> Can't implicitly convert int to model type

This happens near the `User = id` line of code. This happens because I am trying to map an int to a model. I am missing something really basic here but I cannot figure this one out. Any help is appreciated.

`User` class:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int UserNumber { get; set; }
    public string UserFName { get; set; }
    public string UserLName { get; set; }
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }
    public string UserPhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string UserRole { get; set; }
}
```

`Cart` class:

```
public class Cart
{
    public int CartId { get; set; }
    public int CartNumber { get; set; }
    public int CartQty { get; set; }
    public decimal CartTotal { get; set; }

    public ICollection<CartItems> Items { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is the error message not clear? You are trying to assign an integer to a property of type User.

Comment: You should normally have a *int UserId* property in the *Cart* class. You should assign that to it.

Comment: don't you need first to find the appropriate user with this id in your repository? so that you can initialize the entire `User` property for the cart?

Comment: As `ballarnes` said,you'd better to have a foreign key,or you can have a Shadow foreign key,here is the official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key) about relationships.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set the *User* property to int, but in *Cart* class *User* is the *User* object.

```
Cart cart = new()
   {
       CartNumber = num,
       User = id, // here id is int type
       CartQty = 0,
       CartTotal = 0
   };
```

Have a look at *Cart* class:

```
public class Cart
   {
       public int CartId { get; set; }
       public int CartNumber { get; set; }
       public int CartQty { get; set; }
       public decimal CartTotal { get; set; }
       public ICollection<CartItems> Items { get; set; }
       public User User { get; set; } // here User is User type
   }
```

You should change *User* to **int** type or **add new property** e.g. *UserId* depending on your needs.

Comment: if I add a new property in cart class will that be a problem for foreign keys between user and cart

Comment: no, new property must be a foreign key for User table's UserId

Comment: public User User { get; set; } this line is responsible for the foreign key creation in the cart table do I need to remove this and add something like this public int UserID { get; set; }

Comment: I think that you should use both User and UserId properties in Cart table but only UserId must be the foreign key

Answer (score 0):

Because User have type of "User" and not integer, you cannot assign in to it. You can either create new user with id of your input:

```
            var user= new User(){ UserId=id };
            Cart cart = new()
        {
            CartNumber = num,
            User = user ,
            CartQty = 0,
            CartTotal = 0
        };
```

Or you can look for this post:

[Can't implicitly convert int to model type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813342/cant-implicitly-convert-int-to-model-type)